Installing hardie board lap siding over old wooden chiplap siding
I have taken some hail-damaged vinyl siding off my house and found that it was installed over the old wooden chiplap siding, which is in good shape. I need to know if I put a house wrap on, then 2x4 treated boards to fur it out, 1" foam board taped and sealed in between the furring strips then the hardie board siding. Is this way going to cause any problems down the road with condensation or anything?

2x4s are quite the work to use for furring.   I would consider something thinner.    as for the insulation the R value is not nearly as important as closing all of the air gaps.
